# Symfony 5.0 LiipFunctionalTestBundle Form must be an instance of Client instead of KernelBrowser

Tags: symfony5, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I upgrade my project to Symfony 5.0. However, when running tests I get the following error:

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Tests\PagesTestCase::form() must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client, instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser given`

Argument 1 in this form is `$userClient`, which is created with `createClient`. In Symfony 5, `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client` is removed. Why is it still expecting an instance of Client? I am using `LiipFunctionalTestBundle`

I looked into the src of `LiipFunctionalTestBundle` and found  in `QueryCountClient.php` the following:

```php
if (!class_exists(Client::class)) {
    class_alias(KernelBrowser::class, Client::class);
}
```

It seems to me that this should fix the issue, however, it does not. I am clueless about why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still had `Client` somewhere in my code, so it expected a client.